# Use Jquery or any other library on the real page from my popup button

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to run jquery code from a button in my chrome extension.

I put my code in many different files, from background.js, content.js etc but everytime it is "$ is not defined".

> manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "add title via Click",  
    "description": "Be able to add titles",  
    "version": "1.0",    
    "browser_action": { 
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"  
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

> popup.html

```
<!doctype html>  
<html>  
    <head><title>Title</title></head>  
    <body>
        <button id="press">Add title</button>  
        <script src="popup.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

> popup.js

```
function injectTheScript() {
    // Gets all tabs that have the specified properties, or all tabs if no properties are specified (in our case we choose current active tab)
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        // Injects JavaScript code into a page
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "utilities.js"});
    });
}
// adding listener to your button in popup window
document.getElementById('press').addEventListener('click', injectTheScript);
```

> utilities.js

```
/**
 * Gets the desired element on the client page and add extra title on it
 */
function extraTitle() {
    $("h5").append(" - Extra title works");
}

extraTitle();
```

I just want to run code from clicking my popup buttons as if I am running them from the console.

Comment: You need to insert jQuery script first using executeScript.

Comment: Do I need to insert each library myself? Can't I access the libraries already loaded in the page, like carousel or any other third party library?

Comment: Content scripts run in "isolated world". See [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)